# NS_ERROR_FILE_ACCESS_DENIED on downloading attachments using filtaquilla add for thunderbird

Tags: centos, thunderbird

When my filter is triggered, which is supposed to download the attachment from the email, I get this error

**NS_ERROR_FILE_ACCESS_DENIED [nsIFile.createUnique] filtaquilla.js:653**

So I opened the filtaquilla plugin then looked at the line described in the error message console of thunderbird.

Upon checking it seems to be trying to create a file in a certain directory which I can't actually point where it is.

Then as I further checked, the value of directory is

```
let directory = Cc["@mozilla.org/file/local;1"].createInstance(Ci.nsILocalFile)
```

And now I'm really lost. Where is this located? this @mozilla.org/file/local. I think this should be on my computer but I'm not exactly sure where should I look. I'm using CentOs by the way.

Answer (score 0):

For my case, I actually tries to create a file in the folder you identified as the destination of the downloaded attachments.

the folder was only accessible to root and that was the problem. it just had to be modified so it can be accessed by the current user which ran the  thunderbird.